# White question mark while trying to get user's Facebook profile picture in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I store app-scoped-ids in my database, hoping to fetch profile pictures from them via the graph API.

This code:

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + mate.getFacebookId() + "/picture?type=large";

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;

    try {

        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (response != null) {
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }

    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (data != null) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);


    }

    return bitmap;
```

...does not work and returns a white question mark, why?

The url 'https://graph.facebook.com/800397776713349/picture?type=normal' works just fine in chrome.

Comment: does this return a String "mate.getFacebookId() " ?

Comment: yes it does return a string

Comment: have you checked with a hardcoded value like "'https://graph.facebook.com/800397776713349/picture?type=normal'" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon on this line is missing:

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + mate.getFacebookId() + "/picture?type=large"
```

It looks like you're using an invalid Facebook ID. Check that mate.getFacebookId() is returning a **valid** ID. When I use a valid ID, I'm able to return the image successfully inside an AsyncTask:

Use inside Main thread (onCreate, onActivityCreated, etc.):

```
GetImage retrieve = new GetImage((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageview));
retrieve.execute();
```

GetImage:

```
class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private ImageView view;

    public GetImage(ImageView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        //Your exact code goes here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) 
    {
        view.setImageBitmap(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit: Indeed using a hard coded value worked... guess my method was faulty after all..Sorry, been stuck for hours on this